# Diff between double and single quotes in zshrc alias definition

Tags: alias, zsh

I try to write an alias to check the git status for all packages under the same workspace. It is showed below:

```
alias ws-git-status="for d in *; do (cd $d && pwd && git status);done"
```

When I run the alais under my workspace, it reports error:

```
4702 ◯  pwd
/Users/adam/workplace
4c327596e4c7 ॐ  ~/workplace:
4703 ◯  ws-git-status
/usr/share/zsh/5.2/functions
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

But if I use single quote in the alias definition:

```
alias ws-git-status='for d in *; do (cd $d && pwd && git status);done'
```

It works pretty well. I search the diff between double and single quotes [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

It seems the double quote will take the value of `$` but single quote will treat it like a character, which can not explain my case. Could anyone help me with some explanation or useful links? I am confused about this matter and unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Variable references like `$d` are expanded inside double quotes. So in the case of the alias definition you quote, `$d` is expanded when you define the alias which is not what you want. Type `alias ws-git-status` to see how it has been defined.

If you use single quotes, `$d` does not get expanded when defining the alias and it will work as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an alias for this at all; define a function:

```
ws-git-status () {
    for d in *; do
      (cd "$d" && pwd && git status)
    done
}
```