# zsh: How to pass a variable into a command?

Tags: variables, zsh, substitution

I have a one-line instruction that works if I put put in a constant, like so:

```
    westk@westkent:~$ echo $dat | jq -r '.[] | select(.Name == "ADM111_1")'
    {
      "ID": 300035,
      "ProductModelName": "Color LaserJet CP3525dn",
      "SupplierName": "HP",
      "StatusName": "In Use",
      "Name": "ADM111_1",
      "ModifiedDate": "2021-06-23T15:56:06.017Z",
      "ExternalID": "",
      "IP": "18.66.0.26"
    }
```

... but not if I put in a variable, like so:

```
    westk@westkent:~$ pn="ADM111_1"
    westk@westkent:~$ echo $dat | jq -r '.[] | select(.Name == ${pn})'
    jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting IDENT or __loc__ (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
    .[] | select(.Name == ${pn})                       
    jq: 1 compile error
    westk@westkent:~$ echo $dat | jq -r '.[] | select(.Name == $pn)'
    jq: error: $pn is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
    .[] | select(.Name == $pn)                      
    jq: 1 compile error
    westk@westkent:~$
```

I've tried all sorts of permutations on the back-side of the "==", but I can't seem to find the correct syntax.

Things like:

```
    == $(pn)
    == $($(pn))
    == ${${pn}}
    == "\"$pn\""
```

etc etc etc.

Help?

Comment: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Quoting

Comment: Parameter expansion does not happen inside single quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diff between double and single quotes in zshrc alias definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006691/diff-between-double-and-single-quotes-in-zshrc-alias-definition)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE & SOLUTION:

I started this project as a zsh script, so that was in my head when I formulated my question, but as I tinkered more, I realized I was doing my testing in a bash shell.

That difference in shells was not the problem, but it did make me realize my problem is not specific to ZSH, and led me to search StackOverflow with the "jq" keyword instead of "zsh", and that led me to the answer:

[Passing bash variable to jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027395/passing-bash-variable-to-jq)

The code that works for me now is:

```
    echo $dat | jq '.[] | select (.Name == "'"$pn"'")'
```